# Degrees of opacity

Tags: optics

If a principal cause of opacity is the seizure of photons by the atoms in the opaque substance, why is it not possible to drive opacity to translucency by filling the shells to the point where the atoms can no longer grab photons?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, most substances display such behaviour: It is called [saturable absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturable_absorption). The key point here is, that "normal" materials are destroyed by the energy input before their absorption saturates (i.e. burst into flames, evaporate, you name it). Furthermore, there are concurrent processes driven by the energy input, which increase absorption, such as formation of defects in transparent crystals.

So, that you don't see this in every day live has several reasons, among which are:

- the necessary light intensities are very high,
- there are concurrent processes, especially material destruction,
- how well the process works depends on the incident wavelength,
- everyday objects tend to be thick (so they may remain basically non-transparent even if the absorption in some layers is saturated).

There are even technical applications of the effect. One is [Q-switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-switching), which is used for high powered pulsed lasers based on cw designs: A saturable filter is added to the resonator, preventing the onset of stimulated emission until the spontaneous emission reaches the saturation threshold of the filter, this means, that a higher fraction of atoms will be excited, resulting in high pulse powers (i.e. more energy is stored in the lasing medium).